# Subversion Merge Issue

Tags: svn

I am facing an issue in SVN merge. I did a check-in in https://svn.xxxxx/svn/sf/maven/strucfin-parent/branches/85/ on 30th January having revision nos 554267 and 554268.

The revision no 554267 had modifications in 2 files while revision no 554268 had changes in one file. Now on 05th June I merged this branch https://svn.x/svn/sf/maven/xxxxstrucfin-parent/branches/85/ to trunk https://svn.xxxxartners/svn/sf/maven/strucfin-parent/trunk. The merge was successful but it did not pick-up the changes for revision no 554267.

Even today when I am merging back again the 85 branch with trunk, it is not picking up the changes that have been done already in revision no 554267.

I have basically two queries:

1. Why it is not picking up the changes for this revision?
2. Can this issue effect other changes also? And how can we check that?

Comment: Did you use the command line or did you use a GUI for your `svn merge` (such as TortoiseSVN). If you did the former, when you ran your `svn merge` command, did you select the range like `svn merge -r 554267:554268 url/to/branch path/to/trunk` ?

Comment: I used tortoiseSVN to merge

Comment: Okay so if you have the working copy of the trunk checked out, right click on the folder and go to **TortoiseSVN > Properties...** and look for the property that says svn:mergeinfo (there may be multiple). Do you see the property that corresponds to that commit, and if so, does it contain that particular revision? i.e. `url/branches/85:554267-554268` or does it just contain revision 554268? If not, honestly, what seems like the best approach right now is to try and just merge in that revision using another SVN merge call.

Comment: It is showing me as /maven/strucfin-parent/branches/85:554215-554275